# C# How to draw circles from center of screen outwards dynamiclly

Tags: c#, winforms, draw, geometry

So the idea is this: 
I have an input , as the user types a value I want to draw circles on the screen (see picture).

I want the circles to start from mid screen and if the user types another value to re draw the circles accordingly.

I know how to draw but I am not quite certain how the math for what I want to achieve is done.

P.S. I wrote code to auto size the circles if the user enters more than the number that fit the screen, but if he enters less than that I want the circles to be drawn from mid outwards.

C# , WinForms

[image]

Comment: What kind of application are you creating (WinForms, WPF, etc)?

Comment: sorry , should have mentioned , winforms

Comment: reading your question it might not even matter, as you're asking for the math. My bad.

Comment: What do you mean by 'screen'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are looking for something like this:

```
var Start = Height / 2 - NumberOfCircles * CircleSize;

for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCircles; i++)
{
    Draw(Start + (i * CircleSize));
}
```

**PS:** Use the variable `CircleSize` for the actual size of the circle plus some space, and in the function `Draw` you can manage where the circle is going to be drawn

Comment: Will try the code , I am trying to understand the math behind the process

Comment: This code is basically what you commented in the other answer

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple maths in the end. Assume

**diameter** is 100 pixels

**Buffer between circles** is half-radius (50 pixels)

**Width** of screen is 800 pixels

**Height** of screen is 600 pixels

```
--Initial position:

first position: (width / 2, height / 2 - (circles-1) * (diameter + buffer) / 2))

--All subsequent positions:

next position: (previousposition.x, previousposition.y + diameter+ buffer)
```

if you enter 1 circles it would be:

**circle 1:** (400, 300 - (0 * (radius+buffer)/2 =  (400, 300)

If you enter 2 circles it would be:

**circle 1:** (400, 300 - (1 * (radius+buffer)/2 =  (400, 225), **circle 2:** (400, 225 + 150) = (400, 375)

If you enter 3 circles it would be:

**circle 1:** (400, 300 - 2*radius+buffer)/2 = (400, 150), **circle 2:** (400, 150 + 150) = (400, 300), **circle 3:** (400, 300 + 150) = (400, 450)

... and so on.